# Unity Open Console/Terminal and Read Input/Write Output to it

Tags: unity-game-engine, terminal, server, console, client

I want to open a console/terminal window in Unity for a dedicated server. The user would be able to launch the game in a "server mode", which then, instead of launching the game, launches a console window (windows cmd.exe, mac terminal, etc) where the server commands/info could be read/written. I would like to find a way to interface with the OS command prompt.

Comment: For, example, look at thee way Unturned handles the servers

Comment: What is your question? Please, add the code you've tried so far - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Debug.Log("some message");
```

and it's will be shown in debug console of unity and saved to log files.

also may be useful: http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/2986